# Show that $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle = \lVert x\rVert^2_2-\lVert y\rVert^2_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

given $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ I am trying to prove this:
$$\langle x+y,x-y\rangle  = \lVert x\rVert^2_2-\lVert y\rVert^2_2$$

What I tried is using the fact that:
$$\langle x-y,x-y\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle-2\langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y\rangle =\lVert x\rVert^2_2-2\langle x,y\rangle+\lVert y\rVert^2_2.$$

Then, since $y =-(-y),$ I have
$$\langle x+y,x-y\rangle = \langle x-(-)y,x-y\rangle$$

But I don't know how I proceed from this... Maybe my approach is wrong?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters, rather than `<` and `>`.

Comment: You should be able to just expand $\langle x + y, x - y \rangle$. It's a bit like a difference of two squares expansion: $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 - b^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to proceed is by using the bilinearity of the inner product, i.e., just expanding $\langle x+y,x-y\rangle$. Doing this:
$$\begin{align*}
\langle x+y,x-y\rangle &= \langle x,x-y\rangle + \langle y,x-y\rangle\\
 &= \langle x,x\rangle - \langle x,y\rangle + \langle y,x\rangle - \langle y,y\rangle\\
 &= \lVert x\rVert^2 - \lVert y\rVert^2
\end{align*}$$
since the two middle terms cancel out (they are equal, inner product is commutative).